# Valgrind Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

I am writing a program to select words from a txt file.
Compiling flags: -std=gnu99
The program has some segmentation faults that I am debugging with GDB and Valgrind.
Valgrind flags: --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
I have some question about Valgrind error messages

First of all here the code explained

- struct character: is the struct that will contain all the word that
  start with a specific letter, for example a or b or c, ecc.
- include function: when you have to add a word into the specific structure, insert function scans the words array to see if there is an occurrance of this word. If yes, it increase the word count. Otherwise it will add the word to the array. If there is no space, the function increases array space.
- the main is quiet linear. You can see struct for each character of the alphabet, you can see a while loop for reading lines of text file.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>


struct character
{
    char **words;
    int *count;
    int arrayCounter;
};

/*
 * if finds in the array the word to add, then increase counter
 * if it does not find the word, it puts the word non la trova ce la mette nel primo slot che è NULL, quindi vuoto.
 * se non trova slot vuoti aumenta la dimensione degli array e poi torna al punto due.
 */
void insert(struct character *character, char *word)
{
    while(1){
    printf("inserting word %s\n", word);
    for(int i = 0; i < character->arrayCounter; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        if((character->words[i] != NULL) && (strcmp(character->words[i], word) == 0))
        {
            printf("Insert: I found a corrispondence of word in the array, now I increase the word counter in the struct\n");
            printf("Original word: %s word to compare %s\n", character->words[i], word);

            character->count[i] = character->count[i] + 1;
            printf("Word %s counter: %d\n", character->words[i], character->count[i]);
            return;
        }

    }

    ciclo:
    for(int i = 0; i < character->arrayCounter; i++)
    {
        printf("ciclo: %d\n", i);
        if(character->words[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Insert: ho trovato un posto vuoto nello slot %d e ci metto la word %s\n", i, word);
            character->words[i] = malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(character->words[i], word);
            character->count[i] = character->count[i] + 1;
            printf("Insert: controllo, la word è %s, il suo contatore è %d\n", character->words[i], character->count[i]);

            printf("\n\n\n\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("!!!Increasing arrayCounter dimension, now it is %d\n", character->arrayCounter);
    character->words = realloc(character->words, (character->arrayCounter + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    character->count = realloc(character->count, (character->arrayCounter + 1) * sizeof(int));
    character->arrayCounter++;
    printf("!!!Dimension increase, arrayCounter is %d\n", character->arrayCounter);
    /*goto ciclo;*/}
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fileToRead;
    if((fileToRead = fopen("/home/caterpillar/Universita/workspace_Progetti/SO_ricercaParole/testo2.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("error in opening file\n" "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    struct character a;
    memset(&a, 0, sizeof(a));
    a.arrayCounter = 1;
    a.words = malloc((a.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    a.count = calloc(a.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character c;
    memset(&c, 0, sizeof(c));
    c.arrayCounter = 1;
    c.words = malloc((c.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    c.count = calloc(c.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character e;
    memset(&e, 0, sizeof(e));
    e.arrayCounter = 1;
    e.words = malloc((e.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    e.count = calloc(e.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character g;
    memset(&g, 0, sizeof(g));
    g.arrayCounter = 1;
    g.words = malloc((g.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    g.count = calloc(g.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character i;
    memset(&i, 0, sizeof(i));
    i.arrayCounter = 1;
    i.words = malloc((i.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    i.count = calloc(i.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character m;
    memset(&m, 0, sizeof(m));
    m.arrayCounter = 1;
    m.words = malloc((m.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    m.count = calloc(m.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character o;
    memset(&o, 0, sizeof(o));
    o.arrayCounter = 1;
    o.words = malloc((o.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    o.count = calloc(o.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character q;
    memset(&q, 0, sizeof(q));
    q.arrayCounter = 1;
    q.words = malloc((q.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    q.count = calloc(q.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character s;
    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));
    s.arrayCounter = 1;
    s.words = malloc((s.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    s.count = calloc(s.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character u;
    memset(&u, 0, sizeof(u));
    u.arrayCounter = 1;
    u.words = malloc((u.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    u.count = calloc(u.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character z;
    memset(&z, 0, sizeof(z));
    z.arrayCounter = 1;
    z.words = malloc((z.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    z.count = calloc(z.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));





    struct character b;
    memset(&b, 0, sizeof(b));
    b.arrayCounter = 1;
    b.words = malloc((b.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    b.count = calloc(b.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character d;
    memset(&d, 0, sizeof(d));
    d.arrayCounter = 1;
    d.words = malloc((d.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    d.count = calloc(d.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character f;
    memset(&f, 0, sizeof(f));
    f.arrayCounter = 1;
    f.words = malloc((f.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    f.count = calloc(f.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character h;
    memset(&h, 0, sizeof(h));
    h.arrayCounter = 1;
    h.words = malloc((h.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    h.count = calloc(h.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character l;
    memset(&l, 0, sizeof(l));
    l.arrayCounter = 1;
    l.words = malloc((l.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    l.count = calloc(l.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character n;
    memset(&n, 0, sizeof(n));
    n.arrayCounter = 1;
    n.words = malloc((n.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    n.count = calloc(n.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character p;
    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));
    p.arrayCounter = 1;
    p.words = malloc((p.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    p.count = calloc(p.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character r;
    memset(&r, 0, sizeof(r));
    r.arrayCounter = 1;
    r.words = malloc((r.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    r.count = calloc(r.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character t;
    memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));
    t.arrayCounter = 1;
    t.words = malloc((t.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    t.count = calloc(t.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));

    struct character v;
    memset(&v, 0, sizeof(v));
    v.arrayCounter = 1;
    v.words = malloc((v.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
    v.count = calloc(v.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));




    char *line;
    line = malloc(5000*sizeof(char));
    ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
    ssize_t lineLength = 5000;
    //while(fgets(line, 5000, fileToRead) != (NULL))
    while((bytesRead = getline(&line, &lineLength, fileToRead)) != -1)
    {
        line[bytesRead + 1] = '\0';
        printf("linea è %s, strlen è %d\n", line, strlen(line));
        printf("tronco l'accapo\n");
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("Nuova linea è %s, strlen è %d\n", line, strlen(line));
        char *buffer;
        buffer = strtok(line, " ");
        /*if(buffer =! NULL)
        {
            break;
        }*/
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'a'))
        {
            insert(&a, buffer);
        }
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'c'))
        {
            insert(&c, buffer);
        }
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'e'))
        {
            insert(&e, buffer);
        }
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'g'))
        {
            insert(&g, buffer);
        }
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'i'))
        {
            insert(&i, buffer);
        }
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'm'))
        {
            insert(&m, buffer);
        }
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'o'))
        {
            insert(&o, buffer);
        }
        if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'q'))
        {
            insert(&q, buffer);
        }
        if(((buffer != NULL) && buffer[0] == 's'))
        {
            insert(&s, buffer);
        }
        if(((buffer != NULL) && buffer[0] == 'u'))
        {
            insert(&u, buffer);
        }
        if(((buffer != NULL) && buffer[0] == 'z'))
        {
            insert(&z, buffer);
        }

        printf("***********************\n");
        for(int i = 0; (i < a.arrayCounter) && (a.words[i] != NULL); i++)
        {
            printf("Parola %s contatore %d\n", a.words[i], a.count[i]);
        }
        printf("***********************\n");
        //memset(buffer, NULL, 50*sizeof(char));
        while(1)
        {
            printf("while 1\n");
            buffer = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if(buffer == NULL)
            {
                printf("buffer is NULL, exiting from loop and going to next line\n");
                break;
            }

            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'a'))
            {
                insert(&a, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'c'))
            {
                insert(&c, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'e'))
            {
                insert(&e, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'g'))
            {
                insert(&g, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'i'))
            {
                insert(&i, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'm'))
            {
                insert(&m, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'o'))
            {
                insert(&o, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'q'))
            {
                insert(&q, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 's'))
            {
                insert(&s, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'u'))
            {
                insert(&u, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'z'))
            {
                insert(&z, buffer);
            }



            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'b'))
            {
                insert(&b, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'd'))
            {
                insert(&d, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'f'))
            {
                insert(&f, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'h'))
            {
                insert(&h, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'l'))
            {
                insert(&l, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'n'))
            {
                insert(&n, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'p'))
            {
                insert(&p, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'r'))
            {
                insert(&r, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 't'))
            {
                insert(&t, buffer);
            }
            if((buffer != NULL) && (buffer[0] == 'v'))
            {
                insert(&v, buffer);
            }







            //memset(buffer, NULL, 50*sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    printf("***********************\n");
    for(int ii = 0; (ii < c.arrayCounter) && (c.words[ii] != NULL); ii++)
    {
        printf("Word %s count %d\n", c.words[ii], c.count[ii]);
    }
    printf("***********************\n");

    printf("***********************\n");
    for(int ii = 0; (ii < e.arrayCounter) && (e.words[ii] != NULL); ii++)
    {
        printf("Word %s count %d\n", e.words[ii], e.count[ii]);
    }
    printf("***********************\n");
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        printf("!!!!!!!STAMPO PAROLE CHE INIZIANO CON LETTERA %s\n", arrayCaratteri[i]);
        printf("***********************\n");
        for(int ii = 0; (ii < arrayCaratteri[i].arrayCounter) && (arrayCaratteri[i].words[ii] != NULL); ii++)
        {
            printf("Parola %s contatore %d\n", arrayCaratteri[i].words[ii], arrayCaratteri[i].count[ii]);
        }
        printf("***********************\n");
    }*/
    fclose(fileToRead);  // close the file prior to exiting the routine
    free(a.words);
    free(a.count);
    free(b.words);
    free(b.count);
    free(c.words);
    free(c.count);
    free(d.words);
    free(d.count);
    free(e.words);
    free(e.count);
    free(f.words);
    free(f.count);
    free(g.words);
    free(g.count);
    free(h.words);
    free(h.count);
    free(i.words);
    free(i.count);
    free(l.words);
    free(l.count);
    free(m.words);
    free(m.count);
    free(n.words);
    free(n.count);
    free(o.words);
    free(o.count);
    free(p.words);
    free(p.count);
    free(q.words);
    free(q.count);
    free(r.words);
    free(r.count);
    free(s.words);
    free(s.count);
    free(t.words);
    free(t.count);
    free(u.words);
    free(u.count);
    free(v.words);
    free(v.count);
    free(z.words);
    free(z.count);

    printf("terminate successfully\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here some Valgrind error messages about conditional jumps depending on initialized values:

```
[caterpillar@hostname Debug]$ valgrind --track-origins=yes 
--leak-check=full ./SO_ricercaParole 
==2791== Memcheck, a memory error detector 
==2791== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al. 
==2791== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info 
==2791== Command: ./SO_ricercaParole 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x8049520: main (parole.c:325) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048B17: main (parole.c:119) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x8049520: main (parole.c:325) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048B17: main (parole.c:119) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x80496E2: main (parole.c:364) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048E5C: main (parole.c:177) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x80496E2: main (parole.c:364) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048E5C: main (parole.c:177) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048A5D: main (parole.c:107) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048A5D: main (parole.c:107) 
==2791== 
==2791== Use of uninitialised value of size 4 
==2791== at 0x4D9851AB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195) 
==2791== by 0x4D98A03B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x4D9851B3: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195) 
==2791== by 0x4D98A03B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791==
at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x4D98A3FD: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x4D989D7D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x804982B: main (parole.c:392) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x804907E: main (parole.c:219) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791==
by 0x804982B: main (parole.c:392) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x804907E: main (parole.c:219) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x8049584: main (parole.c:333) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048BD1: main (parole.c:131) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x8049584: main (parole.c:333) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048BD1: main (parole.c:131) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x804976F: main (parole.c:376) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048F52: main (parole.c:195) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x804976F: main (parole.c:376) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048F52: main (parole.c:195) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048FE8: main (parole.c:207) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048FE8: main (parole.c:207) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x80494EE: main (parole.c:321) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048ABA: main (parole.c:113) 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x80494EE: main (parole.c:321) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048ABA: main (parole.c:113) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791==
by 0x80497FC: main (parole.c:388) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8049033: main (parole.c:213) 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x80497FC: main (parole.c:388) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8049033: main (parole.c:213) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791==
by 0x80492E6: main (parole.c:267) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048B74: main (parole.c:125) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x80492E6: main (parole.c:267) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048B74: main (parole.c:125) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38) 
==2791== by 0x804964C: main (parole.c:349) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048D45: main (parole.c:155) 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x80487E0: insert (parole.c:54) 
==2791== by 0x804964C: main (parole.c:349) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236) 
==2791== by 0x8048D45: main (parole.c:155) 
==2791== Use of uninitialised value of size 4 
==2791== at 0x4D9851AB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195) 
==2791== by 0x4D98A03B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791==
at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x4D9851B3: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195) 
==2791== by 0x4D98A03B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791==
at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x4D98A3FD: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== 
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 
==2791== at 0x4D989D7D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570) 
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384) 
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation 
==2791== at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525) 
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69) 
==2791== by 0x80497CD: main (parole.c:384)
```

Why this kind of messages? I initialized all structs and arrays, ecc.ecc.

Comment: Seriously?? 450 lines of code and 240 lines of error messages? Couldn't you reduce it to a minimal example?

Comment: Please narrow down your issue. You should be able to reproduce it with about 5% of the code you posted, and you'll probably find the error while you do that.

Comment: Separate struct variable name for each character...?!

Comment: Also, you forgot a fair few letters. (j,k,w,x,y)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
character->words = realloc(character->words, (character->arrayCounter + 1) * sizeof(char*));
character->count = realloc(character->count, (character->arrayCounter + 1) * sizeof(int));
character->arrayCounter++;
```

1. You should *never* use the construct `ptr = realloc(ptr,size);` If `realloc` returns `NULL`, the memory pointed to by `ptr` is leaked and you can't reach it anymore.
2. Don't increase the sizes by just one element, that is inefficient and expensive. Since it also leads to memory fragmentation, it probably doesn't use less memory than an increase by a larger amount, say an increase by a constant factor (double the size, multiply by 1.5 [and add one to make sure the size is really increased]).
3. The new storage in `character->words` doesn't necessarily contain `NULL`, it is uninitialised, as are the original `words` pointers: `a.words = malloc((a.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));`.

Probably 3. is what valgrind reports.

And your code would be *much* shorter and more readable if instead of having a `character` structure named after the character, you had one array and indexed into that array, so e.g. `struct character e;` would correspond to `character_array['e' - 'a'];`.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see you are in the stanzas

```
struct character a;
memset(&a, 0, sizeof(a));
a.arrayCounter = 1;
a.words = malloc((a.arrayCounter)*sizeof(char*));
a.count = calloc(a.arrayCounter,sizeof(int));
```

etc. using `malloc` when you should be using `calloc`. You then later use the contents of `a.words` without first initializing the contents.

**Edit:** Also, your code could really do with some cleaning up. All of your structures and mess could easily be replaced with two hash tables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that valgrind reports (I won't touch on the other ones) is the use of `malloc` and `realloc`. These don't initialise their memory to 0, only `calloc` does that. Valgrind's messages tell you this, for example:

```
==2791== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2791== at 0x80486E1: insert (parole.c:38)
==2791== by 0x8049520: main (parole.c:325)
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation  <<< TELLING YOU THE CAUSE
==2791== at 0x4007D89: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==2791== by 0x8048B17: main (parole.c:119)                  <<< LOCATION IN CODE
```

And, when you fix those up, the errors caused by `realloc` will be the ones left. Again, they tell you what you need to know:

```
==2791== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==2791== at 0x4D9851AB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==2791== by 0x4D98A03B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1570)
==2791== by 0x4D98FF8E: printf (printf.c:35)
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317)
==2791== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2791== at 0x4007E73: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2791== by 0x804892F: insert (parole.c:69)                <<< LOCATION IN CODE
==2791== by 0x80494BC: main (parole.c:317)
```